# How to move a file from one SharePoint folder to another

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I need to move a file from one SharePoint folder to another folder after I click the approve button.

I am getting the error:

```
"user defined type not defined"
```

```
Private Sub Approve_Click()
  Dim sDocPath As String
  Dim sFileName As String
  Dim sTargetPath As String
  Dim sSourcePath As String
  Dim sDriveLetter As String
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim net As WshNetwork

  sDriveLetter = "S:"
  sFileName = "WorkBook.xlsm"

  Set fso = New FileSystemObject & CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sDocPath = ThisWorkbook.path
  ‘sDocPath = ConvertPath(sDocPath)

  Set net = New WshNetwork & CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  Debug.Print "Path to map: " & sDocPath
  net.MapNetworkDrive sDriveLetter, sDocPath

  sSourcePath = sDriveLetter & "\https:\\xxxxxOrder%20Form\" & sFileName
  Debug.Print "Source: " & sSourcePath

  sTargetPath = sDriveLetter "\https:\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" & sFileName
  Debug.Print "Target: " & sTargetPath

  fso.CopyFile sSourcePath, sTargetPath, True

  net.RemoveNetworkDrive sDriveLetter

  Set net = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I *think* I understand what this is attempting to do - and @Pᴇʜ has answered your question in incredible detail, but I don't thing you're setting `sSourcePath` and `sTargetPath` correctly so you're going to hit further troubles along your way here.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add the reference *"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"*:

VBA Editor › Tools › References 
[image]
*<sup>More info see: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-filesystemobject/</sup>*

This method is called *early binding* and you can use it like below (inkluding intelli sense):

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
```

Or you use *late binding* (without setting the reference) and without intelli sense then you need to use the code like below:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

but whit you did looks somehow like a mixture of both which cannot work:

```
Set fso = New FileSystemObject & CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

---

Same for `Set net = New WshNetwork & CreateObject("WScript.Network")` wich must either use the reference *"Windows Script Host Object Model"* and:

```
Dim net As WshNetwork
Set net = New WshNetwork
```

or late binding and:

```
Dim net As Object
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
```

Comment: Okay I edited the code as you suggested and also there was a small mistake in the code where "&" was missing in the line. However, when I try to run the code, it gives me an error which is in Line " Dim fso As Object". It says that "Duplicate declaration in current scope". Any idea how to resolve this now?

Comment: @SiddharthGadekar *"Duplicate declaration in current scope"* means you have `Dim` the same variable twice in your code.

Comment: Hi PEH, I understand I tried to rectify the issue by removing the duplicate commands in the code. Hoever, once I run it again, it gives me a new error which says "Sub or function not defined" in the line "‘sDocPath = ConvertPath(sDocPath)". Any leads on that?

Comment: @SiddharthGadekar actually I can only answer one question per post properly here (see [ask]) but read the error message, it tells you what is wrong! It says the function `ConvertPath` is not defined that means it is not found in your code, because it does not exist.