# Move files between folders in the server with vba

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to move a pdf file from a folder to another both located in the server (a Teams sharepoint).

I've used the code below (which is working perfectly on local) but i got the following error :
[image]

PS : I tried to access the "SourceFileName1" when debugging by copy paste in my browser and the file is here

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
SourceFileName1 = "https://comxx.sharepoint.com/.../folder1/myfile.pdf"
DestinFileName1 = "https://comxx.sharepoint.com/.../folder2/myfile.pdf"
FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName1, Destination:=DestinFileName1
```

I've tried also with a path like this "\\comxx.sharepoint.com....\myfile.pdf" i got another error (below). I thought it was a permission issue but in my code i'm exporting this file (myfile) into the folder1 without problem.
[image]

Do you have any idea about how to handle with this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708682/how-to-move-a-file-from-one-sharepoint-folder-to-another

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've tried both solutions but still the same errors. @KJ i'm logged into the domain and saving my credentials, what i don't understand is that i can write on the sharepoint folder through vba but cannot move files between folders